# Only Flutter web relese build does not work

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

When I run the Flutter web app in Android Studio using the run button or by `flutter run -d Chrome`, everything works just fine.

When I run `flutter build web` and open `$(project_dir)/build/web/index.html`, I get a white screen. There are these errors in the browser console:

```
Failed to load app from a service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag. index.html:85:21

Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///main.dart.js”. index.html:1:1
```

When I run `flutter build web -v` there is following:

```
[  +68 ms] Skipping target: web_entrypoint
[   +1 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[ +311 ms] Skipping target: dart2js
[  +10 ms] invalidated build due to missing files:
/home/vanousek/prg/substance-mix/DOES_NOT_EXIST_RERUN_FOR_WILDCARD954977783
[  +72 ms] web_release_bundle: Starting due to {InvalidatedReasonKind.inputMissing: The following inputs were
missing: /home/vanousek/prg/substance-mix/DOES_NOT_EXIST_RERUN_FOR_WILDCARD954977783,
InvalidatedReasonKind.inputChanged: The following inputs have updated contents:
/home/vanousek/prg/substance-mix/build/web/main.dart.js,build/web/index.html}
[ +121 ms] Manifest contained wildcard assets. Inserting missing file into build graph to force rerun. for
more information see #56466.
```

Answer (score 0):

When building your flutter app for web it's intended to be run on a web server.
Running `flutter build web`, would compile the project into a web project. You can use web hosting providers such as netify, firebase hosting, and Github pages.

Running the `./build/web/index.html` would not show up. That's why you got the errors in the console.

You could run `flutter run --release -d chrome` to run on Chrome in release mode.

**EDIT:**
[image: Chrome Debug]This is chrome DevTools, it seems that the site was looking for the `main.dart.js` and other resources.

I noticed it was pointing towards `https://your_url/main.dart.js` but the resource is located in `https://your_url/substance_mix/main.dart.js`. So it threw 404's.

One solution to this is to edit the `index.html` and add `/substance-mix/` to all resources. Eg. change `scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';` to `scriptTag.src = 'substance_mix/main.dart.js';`

or you can the GitHub Pages configurations. And have your website directly on `https://mikulasvanousek.github.io/`

Comment: It is actually the case on GitHub pages as well. You can see the [web app](https://mikulasvanousek.github.io/substance-mix/) and the [source code](https://github.com/MikulasVanousek/substance-mix/tree/gh-pages).

Comment: I've seen your source everything seems okay! Check for the pr, hope that works!

Comment: I am sorry, what is pr?

Comment: a pull request on github?

Comment: Unfortunately the code in the pull request behaves the same as my code...

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer, I dug deeper into the site and I found something out!

Comment: Wow. Adding /substance-mix/ to the scriptTag.src does indeed work. Is there maybe a way to set the path of the assets, so I do not have to add it manually for every asset for every build?

Comment: Try creating a folder called `substance-mix` and put the asset folder in it. I think this may work. I